# Unity constructor injection with MVVM not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, mvvm, unity-container

I have one scenario where i want to create object of my injection when i do login but i am bit unaware about cycle my service module where my dependency injection mapping defined is called after my LoginViewModel calls.
due to this my `_Service` object is initially  null because `ConfigureModuleCatalog` calls after my `LoginViewModel` calls.
How can i correct this..actually i don't want to use `new Service()` if my object is `null`.
I am using below code for this

LoginViewModel

```
private readonly IService _Service;
public LoginViewModel(IService Service=null) //Also i want to make this innjection optional so i set it to NULL
{
    _Service = Service;
}

private void MethodWhereIWantToUseService()
{
    //_service is coming  NULL because configuration or mapping of injection calls after this
   _Service.MYMethod();
}
```

ServiceModule

```
public class ServicesModule : IModule
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        var container = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnityContainer>();
        container.RegisterType<IService, Service>();

    }
}
```

Bootstrapper i.e. where my module is configured

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
        ModuleCatalog catalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(ServicesModule));          
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call your bootstrapper?

Comment: @grek40 when i do login i call bootstraper.run i.e. in App.xaml.cs  "onstartup"

Comment: How do you create your `LoginViewModel`?